# FromHandlePermanent always returns null in injected DLL

Tags: mfc, inject, afx

I am writing a test automation program, that must interact with a grid control in a legacy MFC application. My program must connect to the legacy app, and read the data from the grid.

I know the HWND of the window that contains the grid, and so now I need to find the CWnd-derived class pointer associated with that HWND. `CWnd::FromHandlePermanent` seems to be my friend, but yes, I know, you cannot call `CWnd::FromHandlePermanent` from outside the application, as the AFX window map (`afxMapHWND()`) is only contained in the target application.

Therefore, I inject a DLL (using `CreateRemoteThread`/`LoadLibrary`) into the target app, and get it to call `FromHandlePermanent`.  But even this is not good enough, because I am not in the thread of the HWND, and `afxMapHWND()` is looking at the wrong local thread storage.

Therefore, in my injected DLL, I also (temporarily) subclass the WndProc of the HWND (`SetWindowLong` etc), then call `SendMessage`. Now I am in the correct thread (the main thread of the target application) and I try to call `CWnd::FromHandlePermanent` with my HWND, but it returns NULL!!
If I look at `afxMapHWND()->m_permanentMap->m_nCount`, we see it is 0. So there are **NO** attached classes in the permanentMap, which seems wrong to me.

**So how can I get the derived CWnd pointer??**

Some other info:

- The Target application is statically linked to MFC
- It's a different version of MFC, the windowclass is AfxWnd70s
- I am using VS2010 to compile the injected DLL
- The injected DLL also links statically to the (VS2010) MFC libraries.

Here is the code in the injected DLL:

```
// this is how we pass the HWND to the target DLL 
// (this shared segment is also loaded in calling app)
#pragma data_seg (".shared")
__declspec(dllexport) HWND  g_hWnd = 0;
#pragma data_seg ()

#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.shared,RWS") 

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CLibSpyMFCDllApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CLibSpyMFCDllApp::CLibSpyMFCDllApp()
{
}
CLibSpyMFCDllApp theApp;

extern CHandleMap* PASCAL afxMapHWND(BOOL bCreate = FALSE);

UINT g_WM_GETGRIDDATA = 0;
WNDPROC wpOrigEditProc; 

LRESULT CALLBACK SpySubProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (g_WM_GETGRIDDATA != 0 && message == g_WM_GETGRIDDATA) {
        CWnd * target1 = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd);
                // fails - target1 is null
        return 0;
    }
    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC ) wpOrigEditProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL CLibSpyMFCDllApp::InitInstance()
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL,  COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    if (g_hWnd) {
        g_WM_GETGRIDDATA = RegisterWindowMessage(L"GetGridData");
        wpOrigEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(g_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) SpySubProc);
        ::SendMessage(g_hWnd, g_WM_GETGRIDDATA, 0, 0);
        SetWindowLong(g_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) wpOrigEditProc); 
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You are looking at the handle map maintained by the MFC library of your DLL. It's not the same handle map maintained by the MFC library of the exe.